# Scala How To Use Map To Store Methods as values

Tags: scala

I have to present a number of options to the user such as:

```
1. Option 1
2. Option 2
Please choose your option:
```

In my scala code, each of the options has its own method associated with it. For example:

```
def method1(){
 println("method1")
}

def method2(){
 println("method2")
}
```

Instead of using a switch statement, I would like to use a map structure like this:

```
val option= Console.readInt
val options= Map(1 -> method1, 2-> method2 )
```

Then I want to call the corresponding method by invoking:

```
options.get(option).get
```

However, when it reaches the line **val options= Map(1 -> method1, 2-> method2 )**, it prints the following:

```
method1
method2
```

Can you please show me directions to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the entire mapping of input to method known at compile time?

Comment: @drstevens: yes. Thanks for your question. I have found the answer from Dan Getz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your methods, which have an argument type of `()`, can be called with or without the parentheses. Just writing the name of the method is parsed as a method call. To get a function as a value that will call your method, you can write an anonymous function with a `_` as a placeholder for the `()` argument:

```
method1 _
```

In your example, this would then be

```
val options = Map(1 -> method1 _, 2 -> method2 _)
options.get(option).get()
```

The parentheses are necessary here. They aren't for the method `get` like it might seem. They're applied to the function object returned by `get`.

Also note that you can replace `map.get(key).get` with the equivalent code `map(key)`:

```
options(option)()
```

As pointed out by @tuxdna, your code will throw an exception if `option` is not one of the keys in the `options` map. One way to avoid that is to do a `match` on the result of `options.get()`:

```
options.get(option) match {
   case Some(f) => f()
   case None => // invalid option selected
}
```

Comment: `options.get(option).get()` may fail on `None`, in which case you can use a `map` operation or a `match/case` pattern matching.